# Canvas draws in one environment, not the other

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create an input form that will take information use it to plot out a simple shape using canvas.

I had it working in the codecademy test environment, but I couldn't figure out how to bring up the console, so I tried migrating it to codepen.io so I could get some output for troubleshooting purposes when needed.
Upon copying it, it no longer draws the shape. Is there something I'm missing?

Here is the script I'm using. I've tried commenting it out line by line but to no avail. I've also tried using jsfiddle with the same result.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    //Initialize canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //Draw settings

    //draw circle!
    function draw() {
        var x = document.getElementById('x').value
        console.log(x)
        var y = document.getElementById('y').value
        var radius = document.getElementById('radius').value
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, 40, 0, Math.PI);
        context.stroke();
    }

    setInterval(draw, 10);
});
```

http://codepen.io/whole_kernel/pen/XKRZVV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of jquery . You are trying use functions which were defined jquery.
Add this in head :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: To add on to her comment, add this script tag at the bottom of your HTML page right before the `</body>` tag. Her method requires an internet connection, so you may want to consider downloading the file and storing it locally possibly in a js folder within your project directory and then using `<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you! Ttransitioning from those learning environments has been tripping me up. There's a bit of boilerplate that's been laid down for me in those tutorials and when it's suddenly not there it's been causing some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer suggests that you use jQuery by linking in that file.

Rather than use the jQuery replace

```
$(document).ready(function(....
```

with

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(....
```

It does the same thing, and your page will load and run quicker. Why load an whole Interface for just one line of code.